# Screen Rendering only 2/3 of eBook - Troubleshooting Ideas?

Tags: kindle

I like my Kindle DX.

Yesterday, I turned it on and found it like this.

[image]

It's fully charged and I reset it but it didn't help.
I chatted with Amazon and they provided 'service fee replacement' option with which I can buy Paperwhite at reduced price.
However, I already have Paperwhite and I like my DX.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify something: is the screen cracked or scratched? Or is the screen physically okay?

Comment: The screen is physically perfect. And when I chatted with Amazon support, they admitted that it's physically ok.

Comment: if they admit that screen is physically ok (I have no idea how they can tell it without even seeing the device) it mean it is software failure. I would try to do an hard reset or try even to remove battery. This [mobileread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=72779) thread showing how you can do hard reset on your device.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no unless you have access to this model e-ink screen. Scratches on display suggests that something or someone just broke the screen. It is not software issue - it is hardware.

Comment: That doesn't really look like scratches on the screen; it looks like display corruption.

Comment: It is my bad English - I mean cracks. Physical damage of screen.

Comment: Your English was fine; I knew you meant physical damage. I'm saying that it doesn't really look like physical damage.

Comment: Sharp edges looks like broken eInk layer. The protection cover may be not damaged but eInk definitely is. I can't have 100% sure unless I see it live but if I have to make a bet my money I would go for physical damage.

Comment: It definitely may be physical, but my Kindle did the same thing once. It went back to normal after a reset, which OP's device apparently did not.

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. The screen is physically perfect even if it looks broken.

Comment: Screen have 2 layers. First is protective one and second is actually an eInk display. It is possible to broke eInk display without breaking protective. But it is only my opinion based on photo. If hard reset of device isn't helping only thing you can do is to contact Amazon. This model is not anymore in sale and I strongly doubt they will want to repair it. They will give you a solid discount for a new device.